# unstack qplot and arrange according to year and month (R)

Tags: r, sorting, ggplot2, dataframe, bar-chart

I need to plot a graph by month and year, continuously. The month and year are stored in two different columns in the same dataframe. I managed to get the plot unstacked, how do I rearrange it so that it plots the variable sequentially according to year and month?

Example data:-

```
              stateOut  stateIn yearShipment monthShipment
            NEGERISEMBILAN    KEDAH         2010       January
                   SELANGOR   PAHANG         2010          June
            NEGERISEMBILAN  SELANGOR         2010      February
            NEGERISEMBILAN  SELANGOR         2010      February
               PULAUPINANG  KELANTAN         2011         March
                      PERAK KELANTAN         2011         April
```

Codes:-

```
qplot(monthShipment,data=df, fill=as.factor(yearShipment), geom="bar", position="dodge") + labs(fill="Year of Shipment")
```

[image: dodge_qplot]

How do I re-arrange this so that the x-axis starts from January 2010 - December 2011?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Oh nevermind, I found the answer. Just swap the columns, like so:-

```
qplot(as.factor(yearShipment),data=df, fill=as.factor(monthShipment), geom="bar", position="dodge", xlab="Month and Year", ylab="Movements")
```